# Kotlin: app crashes when opening ImagePicker

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin noob here.

I just want to ask what does this error mean?

```
2021-08-03 00:29:56.272 15335-15335/com.sakura.sakurafreemarket E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sakura.sakurafreemarket, PID: 15335
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sakura.sakurafreemarket/com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.ImagePickerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: o3.a cannot be cast to q3.a
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: o3.a cannot be cast to q3.a
    at com.esafirm.imagepicker.features.ImagePickerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:61)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

this is the layout code for the button

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPostAdPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_betweem_small_and_medium"
                app:cornerRadius="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:maxHeight="@dimen/margin_large_2"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/margin_large_2"
                android:onClick="@{() -> vm.onSelectPhotos()}"
                android:text="Upload Photo"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_extra_small"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layoutPostAd"/>
```

and this is the ViewModel.kt file

```
var user: User? = null
var radioChecked = MutableLiveData<Int>()
var selectedPhotos = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
var shippingInfo = MutableLiveData<Int>()
var photoId = MutableLiveData<String>()
val photoUriList = mutableListOf<File>()
val photoUpdateUriList = mutableListOf<SelectedPhotoApiResponse>()
val selectedItemResult = MutableLiveData<Resource<GetOneProductResponse>>()
val removePhotoResult = MutableLiveData<Resource<RemovePhotoResponse>>()
var sendPhotoResult = MutableLiveData<Resource<SendItemPhotosResponse>>()
var updateSendPhotoResult = MutableLiveData<Resource<SendItemPhotosResponse>>()
var sendProductResult = MutableLiveData<Resource<SendProductInfoResponse>>()
var updateOrPostStatus = MutableLiveData<Int>()
var productId = MutableLiveData<Int>()

private var imagePathListArray: ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>? = null

var postForm = MutableLiveData<PostForm>()

private val autoCompletePublishSubjectCategory = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectTitle = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectPrice = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectDescription = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectCondition = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectWeight = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectLength = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectWidth = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectHeight = PublishSubject.create<String>()
private val autoCompletePublishSubjectCourier = PublishSubject.create<String>()

private val autoCompletePublishSubjectShippingYes = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

init {

    user = Hawk.get<User>(Constants.PREF_KEY_USER_INFO)?.apply {}

    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectCategory, 300)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredCategory(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectTitle, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredTitle(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectPrice, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredPrice(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectDescription, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredDescription(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectCondition, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredCondition(result) }

    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectWeight, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredWeight(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectLength, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredLength(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectWidth, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredWidth(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectHeight, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredHeight(result) }
    configureInterceptorWithEmpty(autoCompletePublishSubjectCourier, 0)
            .subscribe { result -> filteredCourier(result) }

    initIncludeShipping()
    selectedPhotos.value = false
    postForm.value = PostForm()
}


fun onSelectPhotos() {
    selectedPhotos.value = true
}

companion object {
    const val MULTIPART_MEDIA_TYPE = "multipart/form-data"
}
```

and here is another code from the **Activity.kt** file

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (ImagePicker.shouldHandle(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {

        val images = ImagePicker.getImages(data)

        if (selectedProduct != null) {
            var count = 0
            images.forEach { image ->
                val file = File(image.path)
                vm.photoUpdateUriList.add(SelectedPhotoApiResponse(path = image.path, id = 0, fileImage = file))
                AppLogger.error("$vm.photoUpdateUriList")

                //  updateImagesAdapter.collection = vm.photoUpdateUriList
                photoUpdateListVisibility()

                count++
                AppLogger.error("${images.lastIndex} -- $count -- ${images.size}")
                if (count == images.size) {
                    vm.updateSendPhotos()
                    count = 0
                }
            }

        } else {
            images.forEach { image ->
                val file = File(image.path)
                vm.photoUriList.add(file)
                imagesAdapter.collection = vm.photoUriList

                photoListVisibility()
            }
            vm.setPhotoFile(vm.photoUriList)
        }
    }
}
```

I have this button that opens the imagepicker. upon clicking this button, the app crashes and that error appears on logcat. I'm not really sure how to fix it since I am still studying kotlin. The code is not my original work so I'm kinda stuck on this issue for more than 2 days now.

i am not sure what the `o3.a cannot be cast to q3.a` mean on the stacktrace. Can someone help me understand it so I may be able to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You have Proguard/R8 enabled. You would need to de-obfuscate that stack trace to know what those references refer to.

Comment: Are you running the release version of this app? It looks like it's obfuscated so it's not able to clearly depict the code that's being run.

But also, we'd need to see the code. What's happening is that whatever is being returned from the image picker isn't the correct type. But no way to know without seeing the code.

Comment: @Rafa, yes I am running the release version. I added the code on the post.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tried to disable ProGuard by adding `useProguard false` in the `build.gradle` file, but it's giving me error when I try to run it

Comment: You probably should be using a `debug` build, not a `release` build, when doing day-to-day development.

Comment: using the `debug` build I don't experience those errors